# Undefined is not an object (tensorflow imagerecognition)

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, object-detection, expo

When trying to integrate a pretrained tensorflow model with expo (react-native), the following error occurs within these lines:

```
async classify(photo) {

    try {

        const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
            model: require('./assets/output_graph.pb'),
            labels: require('./assets/output_labels.txt')
        });

        const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
            image: photo,
            inputName: "input", //Optional, defaults to "input"
            inputSize: 224, //Optional, defaults to 224
            outputName: "output", //Optional, defaults to "output"
            maxResults: 3, //Optional, defaults to 3
            threshold: 0.1, //Optional, defaults to 0.1
        });

        results.forEach(result =>
            console.log(
                result.id, // Id of the result
                result.name, // Name of the result
                result.confidence // Confidence value between 0 - 1
            )
        );

        await tfImageRecognition.close(); // Necessary in order to release objects on native side

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

Which generates the following error

```
[23:30:09] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNImageRecognition.initImageRecognizer')
    - node_modules\react-native-tensorflow\index.js:121:35 in TfImageRecognition
```

I have been trying to find the reason why this is not working but I cannot find a definite solution. The relative paths linking to the assets are correct and the extensions are present in the app.json. Furthermore the model is trained using the tensorflow api which should make it compatible with the react-native implementation.

I am using expo SDK version 28.0.0 and react-native-tensorflow version ^0.1.8

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, in my case I forget to link the library.

**Linking**

`$ react-native link react-native-tensorflow`